# Dual boot with Linux, after deletion, grub rescue

Tags: grub

I'm not sure if this is this right place; If it isn't; please redirect me to the correct forum.
I dual booted my computer which originally had Windows 7 installed on it, with Backtrack 5 R3. I went through the install process perfectly and BT was working very well.

I then restarted my system and booted up into Windows. I went into disk management, because I was curious about what partition BT was installed on, and by mistake I deleted the partition that it was installed on.

I thought there was nothing on this partition and was really stupid not to check how much space had been used on the drive. Anyways, I restarted my computer and came up to the screen that says:

"error: unknown file system Grub rescue>!!!!!!
This is EASY to fix, I had it once before with Linux Mint. I just repaired the boot loader with my Windows 7 Recovery Disk. However, this time it is not as simple. I cant boot into ANY CDs/DVDs, including my Windows 7 disk and backtrack, even though my first boot device is set to Internal CD ROM.

The problem is that when I boot up my computer, I cannot access my BIOS. No onscreen keys r shown (the usual F2 on my LG laptop). I have tried all key combinations incase it had switched my BIOS key, which is very unlikely, but it was worth a shot. It just takes me straight to the GRUB rescue prompt where I can virtually do nothing. I,ve tried LS at the rescue and tried to boot up into one of the hard disks, help commands and any other obvious commands that I thought might work, but nothing!

I cant remember off-hand all the model numbers, but my laptop is an LG , as I mentioned above and have a Toshiba HDD.

Anything else you need to know ?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into Windows from your Grub prompt with the following sequence of commands:

```
 root (hd0,0)
 makeactive
 chainloader --force +1
 boot
```

The key command here is the first one, which specifies Grub will have to search for a bootable OS on the first disk (hd0), first partition (the second 0 on the `root` command line). Should your Windows system be on a different disk or partition, you will have to fix this command accordingly.